# D3 Pie Graph Text/Animation

Tags: jquery, animation, d3.js

I currently have a pie graph built in D3.js that looks like this, but with different data

http://jsfiddle.net/bnKgd/

The data is loaded externally with JSON. Here is my code

```
(function() {
    var w = 670,
    h = 326,
    r = 150,
    inner = 80,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

    d3.json("script.php", function (data) {
        var vis = d3.select("#pieGraph")
            .append("svg:svg")
            .data([data])
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
            .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")")

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(inner)
            .outerRadius(r);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
               .append("svg:g")
               .attr("class", "slice")

        arcs.append("svg:path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
            .attr("d", arc)
    })
})();
```

With my data, some of the slices are too small to hold text. I am trying to find options for displaying the information, when I came across this:

http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?javascript,live

How can I mimic these animations? I'd like to know how to add the text/value in the center when the user hovers over the slice. I'd also like to know how to add the arc, and the resize animation. I haven't found any similar examples anywhere, so some help would be great.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is some progress that I made. Add "/1/" to the end of the JSFiddle URL, since I don't have a high enough reputation

I'm still looking for a way to display the text in the center, and the arc animation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the label, add a text element to the center of the pie chart when you create it:

```
var centerText = vis.append("text")
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
```

Update that element on pie slice mouseover:

```
      centerText.text( d3.select(this).datum().data.label );
```

and mouseout:

```
      centerText.text( "" );
```

There are a couple of ways to add the other arc. I would probably change the stroke of the slice path on mouseover, but you could also just draw another inner arc on mouseover.

Comment: This works great! Thanks! Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnKgd/3/. Do you know how to add the arc on the inner radius? That's the only thing I still need

Comment: One question though, how can I change the font attributes (e.g. bold, font-family, font-weight, font-size, etc.). I've tried changing the `.slice text {}` in the css, and add `.style("font-family", "Segoe UI");` to the line you showed.

Comment: I would add .attr("class", "centerText") when centerText is created and use .centerText{font-size:200%; ect;} in the css

Comment: This worked for me too - thank you. Curious though, how you enable html in centerText?

Comment: You could add a foreign object to the svg or position a div over the svg.